# Limit min/max integer on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a talent calculator of sorts, clicking the 'skill' will decrease this variable and right-clicking will increase the variable.

The problem i have is i want the variable to be limited from going over 50 or below 0.

Now ive googled and searched here for variable limits and max integers but nothing gives me an idea how to do this, i think im wording my searches wrong.

Could someone give me an idea how to do this or point me in the right direction please, thanks.

Variable im using:

```
  var a=50;
  function decrease(){a--;document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= +a;}
  function increase(){a++;document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= +a;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function `decrease` after `a--` add

```
if (a < 0)
    a = 0;
```

And in `increase`:

```
if (a > 50)
   a = 50;
```

Or use `Math.min(value, minValue)` and `Math.max(value, maxValue)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Math.min and Math.max.

```
  var a=50;
  function decrease(){ a = Math.max( a-1,0) ; document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= a;}
  function increase(){ a = Math.min( a+1,50); document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= a;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.max(Math.min(x,range.max),range.min);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Makes your code nice and tidy:

```
let a = someFunctionResult();
    a = a > 50 ? 50 : a;  
    a = a <  0 ?  0 : a; 

    // if A is more than 50, make it 50, otherwise leave it unchanged;
    // if A is less than 0, make it 0, otherwise leave it unchanged.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a=50;
function decrease(){
   if(a > 0){
      a--;
      document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= +a;
   }  
}
function increase(){
   if(a < 50){
      a++;
      document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= +a;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var a=50;
  function decrease(){if(a>0){a--;document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= +a;}}
  function increase(){if(a<50){a++;document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= +a;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the value before you change it, so that you only change it if it hasn't reached the limit:

```
var a=50;

function decrease(){
  if (a > 0) {
    a--;
    document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML = a;
  }
}

function increase(){
  if (a < 50) {
    a++;
    document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML = a;
  }
}
```

(The code above assumes integer values. If you assigned `49.9` to the variable and called `increase`, it would increase the variable to `50.9`. If you needed to guard against floating point numbers also, you would do the checks like `if (a - 1 >= 0)` and `if (a + 1 <= 50)`.)

Answer (score -1):

////     your max    /////       your min
if(type > 4){type = 4;} if(type < 0){type = 0;}

simply if its outside either bound set it to that bound

Comment: var a=50;                                                                
  function decrease(){a--;   if((a < 0){a = 0;} 
   document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= a;}
  function increase(){a++; 
if(a > 50){a = 50;}   document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= a;}     sorry I cant for the life of me make this look better